# Out of memory error in php

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, memory, fetchall

I am on php 5.2.5 and executing a script from command line. In this script I am manipulating the data fetched from db. To fetch data from db I am using Zend Adapter.
I notice an **increase in memory(262144 bytes)** after invoking 
 **"fetchAll($sql,$data,Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC)"**

Hence finally leading to out of memory. 
To test I just executed "fetchAll" without even storing the data returned by it in any variable. But still I see an increase in memory which is not reclaimed.

- Is there any memory leak issue with Zend FetchAll method?
- Why does the memory increase by 262144 or in multiples of 262144?
- The memory increase happens randomly and not in all fetchAll calls, why so?

I have tried using memory_get_usage() to determine the cause of memory leak, but since the code is huge it is taking a lot of time, is there any  way I can get the details of all the objects in memory so that I can debug the issue better?

The sql is:-

```
select b.Id as Id,b.Lang 
from groups g 
left join table1 b on b.Group_Id = g.Id 
left join table2 bs on bs.Id = b.Id 
where g.Id = ? and b.Lang = ?
```

Comment: Best would be if you also include the sql command. As it could be a problem in there (for example that you join multiple tables without using a restriction so that every row is joined with every row).

Comment: The sql is 
"select b.Id as Id,b.Lang from groups g left join table1 b on b.Group_Id = g.Id left join table2 bs on bs.Id = b.Id where g.Id = ? and b.Lang = ?". Please could u explain better why the memory usage will increase because of sql statement problem.

Comment: For the leakproblem itself I think the answers are good there. From what I see the sql doesn't cause a general problem (as it restricts which rows are associated with which row). Seems like really either way too many datarows in the tables themselves or a memory leak. 
As you mentioned that the code is huge. Do you unset the variables where you store the input into after they have become obsolete? (as else they still reserve memory)

Comment: I am assuming the variable you are expecting to be unset is $result in this line "$result = fetchAll($sql,$data,Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);" I do not unset the variable as the variable is in the scope of the method so I am expecting that it should not be retained in memory? Could there be a possibility that even variables that are in the scope of a method exists even after the method execution completes?  Please could u also share any good link for the memory leak problem.

Comment: You can use `$this->fetchRow($where);` instead of `fetchAll()`

Answer (score 1):

To return all results at once, they have to be stored in an array in memory. Even if you do not assign that result to any variable, `fetchAll` internally still has to build that array. If there are too many results to store in memory at once, you'll run out of memory; very simple.

As for why the memory is not always reclaimed: there *may* be a memory leak, but it's more likely that PHP's garbage collector simply does not kick in immediately to reclaim the memory. You can try forcing a gc cycle using [`gc_collect_cycles`](http://php.net/gc_collect_cycles) to confirm that.

Comment: Since I am on 5.2.5 I cannot use gc_collect_cycles. Too many results are not not returned for it to run out of memory. The number of results returned is almost same in every iteration. I agree to the fact that memory might not be reclaimed immediately but it should have been reclaimed when php is reaching its memory limit. But the memory simply keeps on increasing after every few iterations.

Comment: I don't have much experience with Zend, but I did use `Zend_Search_Lucene` before which also liked to run out of memory. It may simply be badly coded... :) The simple answer is: if you have out of memory errors, you're storing too much in memory. Plain and simple. Maybe Zend doesn't properly free results, or it caches data internally, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

> To test I just executed "fetchAll" without even storing the data

But you've already stored 2 copies of the data. Most databse clients will maintain a buffer of data returned by the server (in the case of mysql, this has the full data set). When you call fetchAll() then the entire dataset is retrieved to the buffer (if it's not already there) *and* this is then mapped to a PHP array.

Do you have an explicit closeCursor call?

Comment: I am not explicitly calling it , assuming that zend framework would take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just fetch the result row by row without loading it into memory:

```
   /**
    * @var $select \Zend_Db_Select
    **/
    if ($stmt = $select->query()) {
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { //... }
    }
```